# how to migrate orders and products from drupal database to wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, drupal, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

really would appreciate if anyone helps me in this, I have migrated posts, users, comments, images but couldn't find an way to migrate orders and products.

Comment: Analyse the database structure, write an import and export script :-)

Comment: https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-automated-drupal-to-wp-migration/